# Rubik's cube corners backwards?

Tags: rubiks-cube

After long time i took the rubik's cube and wanted to solve it, but i feel like there is something wrong with the corners. Hope that you smart peapole over there can tell me what's going on. [image]

Comment: Welcome to puzzling.SE! Can you post the image of the Rubik's cube, as that might help in knowing exactly what is happening.

Comment: What's wrong is that a corner is missing. You're welcome.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you took the cube apart and are trying to put it back together, the question is how the top layer can all be black on top, but the pieces around the edges don't match.

The answer is that the only cube we see all 3 sides of is the piece in front of us. The blue and orange pieces have a colored face that is oriented towards the inside of the cube, hiding the stickers. Because we can't see the back side of those cubes, this isn't apparent in the picture.

Answer (score 3):

**The piece at top front is from another puzzle**.

There are two pieces shown with black/blue on the same faces - the other is on the top left corner.

There can't be two black/blue pieces with another colour on their left, in the same puzzle. And to think you didn't even bother replacing the missing piece at the bottom!

Comment: This is the correct answer, unless it's two different shades of blue (which would just be ridiculous imo).